# What's the best way to conditionally include an element in a list?

Tags: perl, list, operators

Possible ways:

1. Using [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html):

   ```
   my @list;  
   push @list, 'foo' if $foo;  
   push @list, 'bar' if $bar;
   ```
2. Using the [conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

   ```
   my @list = (  
       $foo ? 'foo' : (),    
       $bar ? 'bar' : (),              
   );
   ```
3. Using the [`x!!` Boolean list squash operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564792):

   ```
   my @list = (  
       ('foo') x!! $foo,  
       ('bar') x!! $bar,  
   );
   ```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: Just a side note, you're not using any of these strings as variable references, are you? No `${$list[0]}`? This just looks suspiciously like a hash to me.

Comment: Poll type questions should CW.

Comment: @Chris: No. I used strings just for simplicity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, they all do different things.

However, all other factors being equal,

```
push @list, 'foo' if $foo;
```

is the statement that conveys its meaning most directly, so it should be preferred.

If you have to pause and think about statement that supposedly does something as simple as pushing an array element, you are doing something wrong.

```
my @list = (
    $foo ? 'foo' : (),
    $bar ? 'bar' : (),
);
```

could be OK if this is part of some colossal initialization that is being done elsewhere.

I think using

```
my @list = (
    ('foo') x!! $foo,
    ('bar') x!! $bar,
);
```

indicates that the programmer has —*how can I put this?*— [issues](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Probeility-of-Success-.aspx).

Incidentally, there is no such thing called the `x!!` composite operator. The `!!` is [double logical negation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Not). It converts an arbitrary false value to a defined but false value (the empty string) which yields `0` when used where `perl` expects a number. A true value is converted to a `1`. Here, `!!` operates on `$foo` and `$bar` and writing it `x!! $foo` unnecessarily obfuscates the meaning of the code.

`x` is the [repetition operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators). So,

```
 ('foo') x !!$foo;
```

means *repeat `('foo')` once or not at all, depending on whether `$foo` is true or false, respectively*.

PS: Of course, it turns out there was a [PerlMonks article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564792) introducing the so-called *boolean list squash operator*. I read the [article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564792) and find it unconvincing.

Comment: Agreed, `x!!` is a little too clever for my taste. I'm hoping that it doesn't gain traction as an idiom.

Comment: Actually `!!` converts a false value to a zero length string.

Comment: @Brad which yields `0` when used in a place where `perl` expects a number. Fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest what I shall dub the "Readable" approach:

```
sub maybe ($$) { $_[1] ? $_[0] : () }

my @list = (
  maybe("foo", $foo),
  maybe("bar", $bar),
);
```

It has many of the benefits of this alleged `x!!` operator (though slightly longer), but with the added bonus that you can actually understand your code when you come back to it later.

EDIT: The prototype doesn't help Perl parse any better and doesn't let us ditch the parenthesis, it just prevents Perl from doing things we don't want. If we want to ditch the parens, we have to do some work. Here's an alternate version that works without parenthesis:

```
sub maybe {
  my($var, $cond, @rest) = @_;
  return @rest unless $cond;
  return $var, @rest;
}

my @list = (
  maybe "foo", $foo,
  maybe "bar", $bar,
);
```

No matter what we do with prototypes, Perl will try to parse it as `maybe("foo", $foo, maybe("bar", $bar))`, so if we want to ditch the parenthesis, we just have to make that give the correct result.

Comment: +1 Also, parentheses around maybe's args are optional because of proto.

Comment: @eugene y - That's why I used a prototype, but it's incorrect. Without parenthesis, it would try to parse as `maybe("foo", $foo, maybe("bar", $bar))`. The prototype rejects this, making sure that Perl doesn't try to do something we don't want it to do. Of course, with a little work we could make it work without parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Either `maybe("foo", $foo)` or `(maybe "foo", $foo)` can be used. Unprototyped version seem to be an overkill to me :)

Comment: This is pretty fantastic.  Clean, elegant, and perl!

Comment: It is baaad. It is *un*readable. First, it introduces new and uncommon function, that shouldn't be used in group development, since every new person has to look up the definition of this function. Second, it uses prototypes and so embarrasses every new developer even more. Third, it takes time to get used to it. Fourth, it is not much shorter than basic Perl constructs cited in the question, hence it's not worth to be introduced at all.

Comment: @codeholic - So if new and uncommon functions shouldn't be used, is all the code you write one long list of calls to built-in functions? I'm sorry, but your assertions are bull. The second one (that I prefer, because I'm crazy) doesn't need prototypes, and the first one only uses them to prevent people from accidentally omitting parenthesis and having it parse incorrectly. In any project, a new developer is going to have to learn a little bit about the internal helper functions and the pre-existing functions to get started, and adding a simple and relatively small one should not be a problem.

Comment: And your last sentence, "it is not much shorter than basic Perl constructs cited in the question, hence it's not worth to be introduced at all," is just silly. Shorter != more readable. Readability is the entire point. `maybe "foo", $foo` is more readable than `("foo") x!! $foo` by a mile. Anyone with any Perl experience should be able to read the first version, and anyone with any experience in a C-like language should be able to read the second, but anyone who reads the project documentation (which all new developers should do) should be able to read mine, regardless of their Perl skill.

Comment: @Chris The Perl code I write is not one long list of calls to built-in functions, because I distinguish helper functions and syntactic sugar. And it's still Perl code, because I realize that Perl has enough syntactic sugar (even may be too much) to aggravate it with your own inventions.

Answer (score 2):

Although the OP didn't call for it, this problem provided me with a good excuse to `use Benchmark;`

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese);

my $foo = 1;
my $bar = "true";

cmpthese( -10, {
  "push" => sub {
      my @list;
      push @list, 'foo' if $foo;
      push @list, 'bar' if $bar;
  },
  "?::" => sub {
      my @list = (
        $foo ? 'foo' : (),
        $bar ? 'bar' : ()
      );
  },
  "x!!" => sub {
      my @list = (
        ('foo') x!! $foo,
        ('bar') x!! $bar
      );
  }
});
```

---

And here are some typical results:

```
         Rate  x!!  ?:: push
x!!  646539/s   --  -8% -12%
?::  701429/s   8%   --  -5%
push 736035/s  14%   5%   --
```

---

Given brian d foy's [7% estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270042/do-comments-affect-perl-performance/270741#270741) for `Benchmark`'s uncertainty, it definitely seems like `push` is the fastest way to grow.

Summing up:

```
$need4speed ? do { push @like $this} : try { something('less' x!! $obfuscated) };
# DISCLAIMER: This is not valid code
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use `$foo ? 'foo' : ()` in such cases, since it is clear (comparing to `('foo') x!! $foo`), doesn't require particular effort to be understood (comparing to `('foo') x !!$foo`) and can be used in the list context (comparing to `push @list, 'foo' if $foo;`).

But, of course, the answer depends on what criteria you choose to choose the *best* option. If you compare them by obfuscation, `('foo') x!! $foo` will surely win. If you compare them by clumsiness, `push @list, 'foo' if $foo;` will be the first. Or maybe you meant performance? I guess not :-)

But if you compare them by good style, my choice is `$foo ? 'foo' : ()`.